# Maven Changelog Plugin-changelog.xml location

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-3

I am using maven-changelog-plugin v2.3 in my project to create changelog xml. It works fine, but it creates the changelog.xml file in target folder and it does not exist in EAR package. I want to add it to EAR package because i will use this data at runtime. How can i do this, which configuration should i add to the dependency below?

Thanks in advance.

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```